# Installing NPM package from gitlab doesn't download all repo files only on CI

Tags: node.js, git, npm, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm using GitLab as my npm package repo. The project consuming this package is using an ssh url and targeting a specific tag. The entry in the consuming projects package.json looks like: `"my-package": "git+ssh://git@gitlab.com:company/repo.git#tag"`

Now to clarify, this works just fine on my dev machine. I can wipe my `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` file, clear my npm cache, and do an `npm i` and `my-package` gets successfully built and installed.

The `package.json` for the `my-package` project has a `prepare` script used to build the package on install. It looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "prepare": "npm run build",
    "clean": "npx rimraf lib",
    "build": "npm run clean && tsc && npx gulp"
  },
```

`my-package` is in a private repo, and so to solve the initial permission issues, I had to create ssh keys, I added the public key to the `my-package` GitLab repo under the Deploy Keys section, as per these instructions https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#deploy-keys.

The `.gitlab-ci.yml` file in the consuming project includes the private key into the ssh-agent like so:

```
before_script:
  - apk update
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apk update -y && apk add openssh-client -y )'
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | ssh-add -
  - ssh-keyscan -H gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

And I have no permission issues. The test stage on the cosuming projects CI looks like this:

```
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - apk update
    - apk --no-cache add --update nodejs nodejs-npm git
    - npm install
    - ls node_modules/my-package/
    - npm run lint
    - npm run test
```

The strange thing is, the `npm install` doesn't download and build `my-package` here (like it does on my computer), it only installs the package.json and readme file. The result of the `ls node_modeuls/my-package` on the ci platform from above results in this:

```
$ ls node_modules/my-package/
package.json
readme.md
```

and of course since my package isn't being downloaded the tests fail to run that use that package.

I've tried a million different permutations of tweaks on both of the projects over the last 2 days. And nothing I do works on the CI platform (yet the whole time it always works locally ). I'd really love to know what I'm overlooking, as since this works on my computer, then there has to be a way for it to work on the CI platform.

Any thoughts?

Comment: So, I got this to work temporarily by not excluding my build directory in my-package. Building locally, removing the `/lib` from `.gitignore` and pushing up the build dir results in the build dir being pulled in on the CI. This works, but is not ideal since one could easily forget to build the project before push, since that's supposed to happen on the consumption of the package.

Comment: Same issue, I don't want to upload the `dist` folder to my repo. `"prepare"` looks like the correct alternative, but seems like it is not triggered. Any update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it,

Solution, add this instruction

`- npm config set unsafe-perm true`

before yours

`- npm install`

> **unsafe-perm**
>
> Default: **false if running as root**, true otherwise
>
> Type: Boolean
>   Set to true to suppress the UID/GID switching when running package scripts. If set explicitly to false, then installing as a non-root user will fail.

This did **NOT** work `npm install --unsafe-perm`